# Increase distance between numbers of numberline

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.7in,right=0.7in,top=0.7in,bottom=0.7in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\setlength\columnsep{10pt} % This is the default columnsep for all pages
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-4,0) -- (4,0)node[right]{$x$};
    \foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}{
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,label=below:$\x$] at (\x,0) {};
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Question: How can i increase the distance between the nodes of numberline?

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5]`?

Answer (score 5):

Three possibilities:

1. Scale the diagram in the x-direction by adding `xscale=N`, where `N` is some number larger than 1, to the `tikzpicture` options..
2. Set the x unit vector to something longer than the default 1cm, by adding `x=Ncm` to the `tikzpicture` options.
3. Multiply all x-coordinates by some number higher than 1.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5]
    \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-4,0) -- (4,0)node[right]{$x$};
    \foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}{
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,label=below:$\x$] at (\x,0) {};
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm]
    \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-4,0) -- (4,0)node[right]{$x$};
    \foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}{
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,label=below:$\x$] at (\x,0) {};
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-4*1.5,0) -- (4*1.5,0)node[right]{$x$};
    \foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}{
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,label=below:$\x$] at (\x*1.5,0) {};
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```